# Python - Sqlite - OperationalError: near "s": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, database, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm getting the following error when trying to add value to a table:

```
line 33, in insert
    c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} (Process, Info) VALUES('{proc}', 
'{inf}')".format(tn=table_name, proc=proc, inf=content))
OperationalError: near "s": syntax error
```

This is happening when using certain text, if I write something regular there is no issue, but for example something like that:

```
#. My item number one
#. My item number two with some more content
    and it's continuing on the second line?
#. My third item::
    Oh wait, we can put code!
#. My four item::
    No way.
.. _bottom:
    Go to top_'''
```

It is failing..
This is the code I am using:

```
def insert(table_name, proc, content):

    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    conn.text_factory = str
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} (Process, Info) VALUES('{proc}', 
              '{inf}')".format(tn=table_name, proc=proc, inf=content))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Appreciate your help guys :)

Answer (score 9):

The syntax error is caused by you interpolating data containing metacharacters into your SQL query. In your specific example, your data contains a `'` character, and that signals the end of a string. The next character, `s` is then a syntax error.

Do *not* use `str.format()` to put your data into a query. Use SQL parameters and leave proper escaping to the database driver:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} (Process, Info) VALUES(?, ?)".format(tn=table_name),
          (proc, content))
```

The two `?` characters act as placeholders for the database driver to insert the values from the `(proc, content)` tuple. The driver will take care of properly escaping the values.

Because SQL parameters can only be used for *values*, not object names such as tables, you still would use string formatting to insert the table name.  You need to make **100% certain** that you don't accept arbitrary untrusted data for the `table_name` variable. Vet that data against a list of valid table names first, for example.

Comment: Could use a bit of info about sql injection as why you don't want to use `str.format()`. But overall good explanation.